# Inheritance and calling member functions

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm fairly new to object-oriented program, so maybe this is a basic question, but I'd appreciate any help you can offer.

If I have a class B, which is derived from class A, is there some way for objects of class B to access class B's member functions from within member functions of class A? So in the example below I might have a call to function2 from within function1 if the object initially calling function1 is of type B. Is this possible, and if so, how do I accomplish it? Thanks!

```
   class A
    {
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        A(){}
        A(int a, int b) { this->a = a; this->b = b; }
        int function1();// { call function2 if class B } 
    };
    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        int c;
        int d;
        B(){}
        B(int c, int d) { this->c = c; this->d = d; }
        int function2(); 
    };
```

Answer (score 4):

A function inside `A` doesn't have any idea of the fact that a class `B` which extends `A` exists and which methods it has.

To be able to invoke a specific method implemented in B from A you need to declare it in A as `virtual`, possibly pure virtual (`= 0`).

```
class A {
  protected:
    virtual void function2() = 0;

  public:
    void function1() { this->function2(); }
}

class B : public A {
  protected:
    void function2() override { ... }
}
```

A `virtual` method is resolved at runtime, this means that when invoked, the more specific implementation for the object on which it is called is executed. A pure `virtual` method doesn't have any base implementation, this makes `A` abstract and forbids its instantiation.

EDIT: a final note, don't call `virtual` methods from base constructors or destructors. It is dangerous and a bad practice, not that this is your case but you never know.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You need to define `function2()` as a virtual function in class A. Then calling it from `function1` will result in B's `function2()` being called if the object is actually a `B`. For example:

```
   class A
    {
    public:
        int a;
        int b;
        A(){}
        A(int a, int b) { this->a = a; this->b = b; }
        int function1() { return this->function2(); } 
        virtual int function2() { return 0; }
    };
    class B : public A
    {
    public:
        int c;
        int d;
        B(){}
        B(int c, int d) { this->c = c; this->d = d; }
        int function2() override { return 999; }
    };
```

If there is no sensible implementation of `function2` for `A`, then it would never make sense to have an `A` object. You can express this by declaring `function2` to be pure virtual; e.g.

```
  virtual int function2() = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

virtual allows you to override function in parent class.

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){}
    A(int a, int b):a(a), b(b) {}
    int function1() { return this->function2(); } 
    virtual int function2() { //what function2 in parent class should do }
private:
    int a;
    int b;
};
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){}
    B(int c, int d):c(c), d(d) {}
    int function2() { //what function2 in child class should do }
private:
    int c;
    int d;
};
```